# java parse regex multiple capture groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Hi I need to be able to handle both of these scenarios

> John, party of 4
>   william, party of 6 dislikes John, jeff

What I want to capture is

- From string 1: John, 4
- From String 2: william, 6, john, jeff

I'm pretty stumped at how to achieve this

I know that `([^,])+` gives me the first group (just the name before the comma, without including the comma) but I have no clue on how to concatenate the other portion of the expression.

Comment: try this regex (?:(?:^| )(?:[^A-Za-z, ])?([^, ]+))+ this is for get names

Comment: Would you mind splitting your strings or quoting them? I can't tell which is string 1 and which is string 2.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Joe, Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .A simple improvement would be surrounding the code blocks with back-ticks ` `

Comment: thank you all! Sorry about the formatting @jkinkead

Comment: thanks @PedroLobito

Comment: @Joe You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\w+)(?:,\s*party of (\d+)|(?![^,]))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0qiQhA/1).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?:,\s*party of (\d+)|(?![^,]))` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `,\s*party of (\d+)` - `,`, then 0+ whitespaces, then `party of` and a space, and then Group 2 capturing 1+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?![^,])` - a location that is followed with `,` or end of string.

[See Java demo](http://rextester.com/HGZA11192):

```
String regex = "(\\w+)(?:,\\s*party of (\\d+)|(?![^,]))";
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("John, party of 4", "william, party of 6 dislikes John, jeff");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.println("-------- Testing '" + s + "':");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + ": " + (matcher.group(2) != null ? matcher.group(2) : "N/A"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-------- Testing 'John, party of 4':
John: 4
-------- Testing 'william, party of 6 dislikes John, jeff':
william: 6
John: N/A
jeff: N/A
```